# Removing MSB bit of a image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, python-imaging-library

can I remove MSB bit of a image without using open cv or matlab in python

```
img = Image.open(image)
arrayimg = asarray(img)
```

i have already read the image nd it is converted to array too, now i want to remove MSB of each pixel from this image

the image is a greyscale 2d image of size 512*512

i have tried to resize the image to 0,255, covert that unit8 and then map , but it doesn't seem to work

```
img1 = (img1 * 255).round().astype(np.uint8)

mask = np.full(img1.shape, 0x7E, dtype=np.uint8)
res = np.bitwise_and(img1, mask)
plt.imshow(res)
```

Comment: show us the output please

Comment: Why do you want to zero the MSB? What effect are you hoping to achieve? Or what issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: What exactly was the goal of calculating `img1 * 255`? Did you think that would change the width and height?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Python Image Library (PIL) you can use the `eval` function: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.eval

```
from PIL import Image
img1 = Image.open(image)
img2 = Image.eval(img1, lambda x: x // 2)
```

Now img2 will have every pixel value reduced by a factor of 2, compared to img.  This effectively clears the MSB.

Comment: that doesn't just clear the MSB, that's a shift. clearing the MSB would be equivalent to calculating `x % 128`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the image
img = Image.open("image.png")

# Convert the image to an array
arrayimg = np.asarray(img)

# Get the shape of the image
height, width = arrayimg.shape

# Create a mask to remove the MSB bit
mask = np.full((height, width), 0x7E, dtype=np.uint8)

# Apply the mask to the image
res = np.bitwise_and(arrayimg, mask)

# Display the image
plt.imshow(res)
plt.show()
```

Each pixel in the picture will have its MSB bit removed by this code, which will then show the resultant image. Also, The file size of an image can be decreased or a stylistic look can be produced with this approach.

Comment: This looks like a ChatGPT answer...

Comment: thank you, but can i clear msb  multiple times